# Proof of: For all linearly ordered sets $X$, if there is a bijection from $n∈ℕ$ to $X$, then $n$ and $X$ are order-isomorphic

Tags: proof-explanation, order-theory

The theorem is:
[image]

This is the full proof given by my textbook:

[image]
[image]

I don't understand the structure of this proof.
 The proof goes:

1. Inductive hypothesis (the one i stated in the title of the question)
2. Define $f|ₙ:n→A\setminus\{f(n)\}$ is a bijection
3. Codomain of $f|ₙ$ is linearly ordered
4. Then by the inductive hypothesis there exist an order-isomorphism $g:n→A\setminus\{f(n)\}$
5. construct an order-isomorphism $h$ using $g$

and then i get lost.

Why do they define $h$ in two ways (the definition before the image and the definition after the image)?
Another thing i don't understand is, a proof by induction is a proof of the type:

[image]

Where is the $p(n+1)$ in this proof?

Answer (score 1):

It is a case study. First definition of $h$ is for the case $S\ne\emptyset$ and the second one is for the case $S=\emptyset$. In both cases, they show such an order-isomorphism exists.

For your second question, $p(n+1)$ is the construction of an order-isomorphism from $n+1$ (or $n^+, S(n))$ to $A$ when it is given that there is a bijection between $n+1$ and $A$.

Comment: You mean that:

the inductive step is given by the fact that the domain of h is $n^+$ while the domain of $f|ₙ$ is $n$ and $h$ is an order-isomorphism?

or

by the fact that the domain of $g$ is $n$ and e definition of $h$ is $n^+$? and $h$ is an order-isomorphism?

Comment: @AndreaBurgio Your inductive assumption is “If there is a bijection between $n$ and $A$, then there is an order-isomorphism between them.” You want to prove “If there is a bijection between $n+1$ and $A$, then there is an order-isomorphism between them.” How do you prove such a statement? You assume that there is a bijection between $n+1$ and $A$, then you construct an order-isomorphism (in this case, it is $h$). You use the inductive assumption to obtain $g$ (since the restriction of $f$ to $n$ is a bijection).

Comment: But how? to prove that "If there is a bijection between n and A, then there is an order-isomorphism between them” by induction shouldn't you assume "If there is a bijection between n and A, then there is an order-isomorphism between them” which is $p(n)$ and derive "If there is a bijection between n+1 and A, then there is an order-isomorphism between them? if you assume "If there is a bijection between n+1 and A, then there is an order-isomorphism between them” aren't you assuming $p(n+1)$?

Comment: @AndreaBurgio I am not assuming “If there is a bijection between $n+1$ and $A$, then there is an order-isomorphism between them.” It is a statement of the form “If $P$, then $Q$”, so I am assuming $P$, then I conclude that $Q$ is true.

Comment: But is that $p(n)$ or $p(n+1)$? I'm so confused..

Comment: @AndreaBurgio Just think about how you prove a normal conditional statement. You assume the “if part” and you reach the conclusion. In this case, it is exactly the same. You want to prove $p(n+1)$, which is a conditional statement, you assume the “if part” and you reach the conclusion.

Comment: Yeah but that's exactly my problem, I don't understand what $p(n)$ and $p(n+1)$ are..

Comment: @AndreaBurgio $p(n)$ is “if there is a bijection between $n$ and $A$, then there is an order-isomorphism between them.” $p(n+1)$ is the same except $n$ is replaced by $n+1$. You assume $p(n)$ (inductive assumption), then you assume the “if part” of $p(n+1)$ (normal way to prove any conditional statement), then you reach the conclusion part of $p(n+1)$.